# Rails - How can I avoid using the database while performing a detect method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When performing `detect` on a int array, it works:

```
@number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].detect{|n| n == 4}
```

Variable `@number` becomes 4.

But when I do something like this:

```
@categories = Category.all
@current_category = @categories.detect{|cat| cat.id == params[:category]}
```

The program outputs

`Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"`

Which means it's using the database to find it.

However, the element I'm trying to find is already in the collection `@categories`, I just want to find it to assign it to a variable.

Of course another solution would be to implement a linear search algorithm, but I just want to keep the code as clean as possible.

How can I avoid using the database for this search?

**EDIT**: I just realized that this could be lazy fetching. Because before `detect`, I never use `@categories`, so it does the query when I do `detect`. Could this be true?

Answer (score 1):

Rails is actually performing a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query when you call `@categories.all`, essentially performing a lazy-fetch.

Your `@categories` object still needs to query the database for the data.

See the documentation here:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/all

```
posts = Post.all
posts.size # Fires "select count(*) from  posts" and returns the count
posts.each {|p| puts p.name } # Fires "select * from posts" and loads post objects

fruits = Fruit.all
fruits = fruits.where(color: 'red') if options[:red_only]
fruits = fruits.limit(10) if limited?
```

Comment: Yeah thanks I just kind of figured out that this could be lazy fetching, because I'm not using the data prior to detect. But when I use it, this "extra query" disappears, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use active record and SQL requesting.

```
@current_category = @categories.find_by(id: params[:category])
```

Using array methods on Active Record relations tend to fetch all the data then apply the algorithm in-memory, while SQL filtering is faster.

In you case I love to define the operator `[]` on my model:

```
#in category.rb
def self.[](x)
  self.find_by(id: x)
end

# anywhere after:
if c = Category[params[:id]]
  puts "Category found and it's #{c.name} !"
else
  puts "Not found :("
end
```